# Docker build of MYSQL will just not start, on the image I'm building

Tags: mysql, docker

Im building a image with a MYSQL database Im very, very, very, new to this, just learning and have no real background just linux use knowledge, the image is a pulled mysql image, I then used the following script to build the image, it goes through the hole process but when it gets to the end it just will not start MYSQL and hangs on the loop...[Image of the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB048.png)...

### Heres the Dockerfile I created...

```
FROM mysql

RUN mkdir /sql

COPY passwords.env /passwords.env
RUN cat /passwords.env

RUN chmod +x /passwords.env

RUN echo "Loading environment variables from passwords file"
RUN . /passwords.env

COPY sql/main.sql /sql/main.sql
RUN cat /sql/main.sql
COPY sql/logs.sql /sql/logs.sql
RUN cat /sql/logs.sql
COPY sql/item_db.sql /sql/item_db.sql
RUN cat /sql/item_db.sql
COPY sql/mob_db.sql /sql/mob_db.sql
RUN cat /sql/mob_db.sql
COPY sql/mob_skill_db.sql /sql/mob_skill_db.sql
RUN cat /sql/mob_skill_db.sql
COPY sql/item_db2.sql /sql/item_db2.sql
RUN cat /sql/item_db2.sql
COPY sql/mob_db2.sql /sql/mob_db2.sql
RUN cat /sql/mob_db2.sql
COPY sql/mob_skill_db2.sql /sql/mob_skill_db2.sql
RUN cat /sql/mob_skill_db2.sql

# Copy the initialization script into the container
COPY sql_setup.sql /sql_setup.sql
RUN cat /sql_setup.sql

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN chmod 644 /etc/mysql/my.cnf

RUN cp -r /sql /mysql_backups/

EXPOSE 3306

RUN until mysqladmin ping -h"$DB_HOST" --silent; do \
    echo "Waiting for MySQL server to be up..."; \
    sleep 1; \
done

CMD ["sh", "-c", "mysqld & sleep 10 && mysql < /sql_setup.sql && wait"]
```

---

Any help would be appreciated thank you guys in advance, for taking the time to read this ;)

I have no idea where to start I've drawn a blank honestly!

Comment: Your script seems to be confusing the option `--silent` with the name of the MySQL host.

Comment: Can't see anywhere where you've set the `DB_HOST` arg or env property

Comment: The DB_HOST is in a file called passwords and uses the following currently 
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
HERCRODBUSR_PASSWORD=password
USER_ADD_PASSWORD=password

DB_HOST=159.203.9.67
DB_USER=hercules
DB_PASSWORD=password

Its just a disposable droplet Im using no wories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you never define `DB_HOST` as an `ENV` or `ARG` so it will never be set.

Second, when running commands in the container, the DB host is `localhost`.

And finally, you shouldn't be adding a healthcheck into your image build as a `RUN` command. The server hasn't even started at that point.

Use [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) instead

```dockerfile
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s CMD ["mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
```

Comment: This solved the problem of building, thank you so much!!! 
Now the container crashes at like 26 to 30 seconds of running so I gotta figure that out lol